# How to find out which program can open a given file?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, file-opening

Let's say I have a file `thesis.pdf` or `picture.jpg`

Is there a command which returns a program to open this file with?

I am aware of the command `file`, but it just returns the correct type of the file (I know that this is not specified by its extension in Linux) and not a program.

I am expecting something like:

```
$ program 'picture.jpg' 
gimp, gwenview, eog
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> mimeopen -a 'picture.jpg'

This is what you need

It will give you output like this

```
Please choose an application

    1) Shotwell Viewer  (shotwell-viewer)
    2) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
    3) Image Viewer  (eog)
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Love Linux - always some new great command to discover...  :-))

Answer (score 4):

Use: `mimeopen -a 0001.jpg`

`-a` will first **Ask** you to choose, not run it.

Please choose an application

```
1) Wine Internet Explorer  (wine-extension-jfif)
2) Wine Internet Explorer  (wine-extension-jpe)
3) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
4) Luminance HDR  (luminance-hdr)
5) ImageMagick (display)  (display.im6)
6) Image Viewer  (eog)
7) Shutter  (shutter)
8) Phatch Image Inspector  (phatch-inspector)
9) Phatch PHoto bATCH Processor  (phatch)
10) Shotwell Viewer  (shotwell-viewer)
11) GIMP Image Editor  (gimp)
```

use application #